# MySQL best way for generate primary key instead of using auto increments

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to generate a primary key for store maximum limit of record in MySQL instead of auto-increment?

if you want to store user taxi booking record then, if booking_id is the primary key. in an example scenario, want to backup and users oldest record but keep recent records up to last 3 months. so in the auto-increment key is not suitable for this scenario. So anybody asks for the best solution to generate a primary key without auto-increment.

how to generate a primary key with PHP code or other MySQL functions

Comment: Not sure why auto-inc is not suitable, surely it will help in ensuring that each booking would have a unique number.  Nothing stopping you deleting older records (or archiving them).

Comment: for the scenario you suggest  the tipical solution is based on an autoincrement  ..  eventually you need  some indexes on others column for an easy application and service management ..

Comment: I think you may have some incorrect assumptions about what a primary key does. I'd start by reading this ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key

Answer (score 1):

You can use UUID v4 or UUID v5. If your PHP version is >= 7.2, you can use this library which does all the hard work for you: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

MySQL from version 8.0 can also generate UUID (https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/)

Btw you can still use auto_increment while deleting records. The only gotha with auto_increment in MySQL is when you remove *all* records from table and then restart MySQL server - it will reset auto_increment as well (at least on MySQL 5.x). Also remember you can always set auto_increment manually (ie. after restarting mysql).

Comment: Some reference on that auto_increment reset issue ~ [MySql autoincrement counter resetting after server restart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80564/mysql-autoincrement-counter-resetting-after-server-restart)